# Yii2 Implement client side unique validation for input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I've one field in my big form i.e.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
```

Following is my ActiveForm options configuration:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
            //'id' => 'printerForm',                
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'options' => [
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            ]
]);
?>
```

I want to implement client side unique validation for this. I'm using unique validator for it but its only working for server side validation.

```
public function rules() {
        return [
     [['name'], 'unique'],
]
...
other validations
...
};
```

Other validations working perfectly but unique client side validation is not working.

Comment: because field name not matching with model attribute name.

Comment: @IncognitoSkulll: Actually its very big form having more than 60+ input, dropdown, radio, checkbox etc.. fields.

Comment: @IncognitoSkulll: all client side validations are working except unique

Comment: don't use custom id for fields otherwise validation won't work.

Comment: No no .. I'm not using custom id bcoz it generates id dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94058/discussion-between-incognito-skulll-and-sky).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I did it myself by enabling AJAX validation for a single input field and by using isAjax so that the server can handle the AJAX validation requests.

Following is the code:

In view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name',['enableAjaxValidation' => true, 'validateOnChange' => false])->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
```

And in controller:

```
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $nm= $_POST['BusinessProcessProfile']['name'];
            $result = Model::find()->select(['name'])->where(['name' => "$nm"])->one();
            if ($result) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model, 'name');
            } else {
                return false;
    }
}
```

It automatically calls validations rules defined in the Model.

For more info please refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#client-side-validation